# Probability, Mass Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For what values of constant C does the function $p(k)=C3^{−k}+4^{−k−1}$ defined on the non-negative integers k=0, 1, 2, … constitutes a (probability) mass function?

The analogous probability "density" for continuous random variables can be interpreted in the same way. If $f\left(x\right)$ is your probability density, then

$$
\int_a^b f\left(x\right) dx
$$

can be interpreted as a "mass".

But I don't understand this when i tried to compute some values, i found that the possible values are 3/4 and 1/3, but i´m not sure at all, please if you can help me.

Comment: If it's defined on *all* the nonnegative integers, then there are none, since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty -2k+3$ diverges.

Comment: sorry i edited the question, i put incorrectly the equation.

Comment: You need to solve the equation $C\sum_{k=0}^\infty 3^{-k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-k-1}=1$. This is an increasing function of $C$, so there will be only one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\{p_k\}$ to be a probability mass function, we must have
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (C3^{-k} + 4^{-k-1}) = \frac32 C + \frac13=1, $$
which implies that $C = \frac49$.